# How to hide backend ssl certificate when proxy passing through an nginx reverse proxy

Tags: nginx

I'm configuring a reverse proxy that an external provider will be calling. One of their conditions is that SNI cannot be enabled on that server so I have to make sure I only return one SSL certificate. I installed an SSL cert on the endpoint:

```
ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/GoDaddyOfficial/redacted.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/GoDaddyOfficial/redacted.com.key;    
ssl_verify_client off;
```

I also have this configuration to proxy pass requests to the backend server:

```
location /whatever{
         proxy_set_header  Content-Type  application/x-www-form-urlencoded;
        proxy_pass https://redacted:443/get/message; 
        }
```

My issue is that 2 SSL certificates are being returned when testing the endpoint here:

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

and the client is saying the reason they are unable to use our endpoint is because 2 certificates are being returned.

The 2 certificates are the one I installed in nginx and the one installed on the backend: https://redacted:443/get/message

Is there any way to hide or prevent the SSL certificate on the backend from passing through nginx and only returning the SSL certificate defined in the nginx config file?

Comment: Well, first, you need to push back hard on the external provider who doesn't want to use SNI because they can't be bothered to upgrade from Windows XP or hire competent developers. It's 2019; that sort of insanity should not be tolerated. Second, ssllabs will actually show a blue bar in the test result if SNI is actually required to view your site. If it's not there, you have some other problem.

Comment: I completely agree. I wish I was able to push back but because of the lucrative business opportunity (namely keeping my job) I have to work with them. Is there any way to prevent returning the backend or upstream ssl cert and only the one defined in the config file?

Comment: I don't even know if you're having a problem at all, let alone what it is. There just isn't enough information here. What did ssllabs show you? Can you show any real information? If not, then it will be very difficult to help you.

Comment: @MichaelHampton https://pcc.enquiresolutions.com:443/adt is the reverse proxy url and it's pointing to https://test.enquiresolutions.com/. If I put the url https://pcc.enquiresolutions:443.com into ssllabs I get the certificate installed at pcc.enquiresolutions.com as well as the site its pointing to: test.enquiresolutions.com

Comment: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=pcc.enquiresolutions.com&hideResults=on&latest

Comment: That doesn't look like an SNI issue. It looks like you've accidentally included the _old_ wildcard certificate in your bundle along with the _new_ one.

Comment: @MichaelHampton hey thanks! That actually led me to the solution. There was another API created there using the the same SSL as the test site. What's weird is they both have server_name defined differently so I thought they would serve different SSL certs but that's a problem I can figure out. thanks!